# ¿Cómo soluciono el problema de variable duplicada en mi método?

Tags: java

He creado el siguiente método:

```
public static animal dar_de_alta(String *nombre*,String nombre_animal,long numero_chip,String recinto,String fecha_nacimiento,String fecha_llegada,String sexo,String origen) {
        
        return animal *nombre*=new animal(nombre_animal,numero_chip,recinto,fecha_nacimiento,fecha_llegada,sexo,origen);
        
    }
```

Es un método que crea un objeto de una clase con el nombre que le pasamos como parámetro *nombre*.

El problema reside en que no me deja ponerle el ese nombre por que lo declaro como parámetro de entrada dándome un error de **Duplicate variable**.

¿Alguna solución?

Gracias por adelantado¡

Comment: Veo varias respuestas de compañeros pero ninguno ha tenido a bien citar una de las reglas básicas de java, los métodos y variables se escriben siempre en camelCase, no snake_case. Es decir, sería `darDeAlta(...` y `nombreAnimal`. Además, los nombres de clase van en PascalCase, igual que métodos y variables pero con la primera en mayúscula también. Las buenas prácticas, estándares y convenciones es mejor aprenderlos de primeras que luego tener que "reaprender" y quitarse malas costumbres :)

Answer (score 1):

Una solución sería la siguiente:

```
public static animal dar_de_alta(String nombre,String nombre_animal,long numero_chip,String recinto,String fecha_nacimiento,String fecha_llegada,String sexo,String origen) {
        
        return new animal(nombre_animal,numero_chip,recinto,fecha_nacimiento,fecha_llegada,sexo,origen);
        
    }
```

Al llamar al método, meteríamos el resultado en un objeto.

No obstante, lo que quiero es llamarlo pasándole el nombre del objeto y que lo genere automáticamente.

Comment: Mira la respuesta que agregué. En cuanto a que deseas llamar el objeto con el "nombre" que defines, en realidad no tendría ninguna utilidad dentro del método, ya que al llamar el método dar_de_alta() ahí se podría llamar con otro nombre el objeto.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más parecido que se me ocurre a lo que quieres hacer es:

```
public static animal dar_de_alta( animal nombre, String nombre_animal, long numero_chip, String recinto, String fecha_nacimiento, String fecha_llegada, String sexo, String origen ) {
    nombre = new animal( nombre_animal, numero_chip, recinto, fecha_nacimiento, fecha_llegada, sexo, origen );
    return nombre;
}
```

Pasas como parámetro el objeto animal sin instanciar (con el nombre que te plazca), lo instancias y lo devuelves.

Nota: yo personalmente y para que la lectura sea más limpia, pasaría todos los parámetros que son **String** en un array:

```
public animal dar_de_alta( animal nombre, String datos[], long numero_chip, ) {
    nombre = new animal( datos[ 0 ], numero_chip, datos[ 1 ], datos[ 2 ], datos[ 3 ], datos[ 4 ], datos[ 5 ] );
    return nombre;
}
```

También le quité el **static**, ya que no creo que sea necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Es redundante crear una variable en tu método, simplemente puedes retornar la instancia:

```
 public static animal dar_de_alta(String nombre,String nombre_animal,long numero_chip,String recinto,String fecha_nacimiento,String fecha_llegada,String sexo,String origen) {
    return new animal(nombre_animal,numero_chip,recinto,fecha_nacimiento,fecha_llegada,sexo,origen);       
}
```

pero en tu clase `animal` debes tener el siguiente constructor, que no hace uso de la variable nombre:

```
public animal(String nombre_animal, long numero_chip, String recinto, String fecha_nacimiento, String fecha_llegada, String sexo, String origen) {
     //...
     // TODO
     //...
}
```

Comment: Si, la variable que le introducimos al método *nombre* no hace falta. Lo que quiero realmente es que me genere objetos aleatorios directamente sin tener que retornar nada. Creo que no es posible. Y si, mi constructor no tiene la variable *nombre*. Nombre la utilizaría para asignarle ese mismo nombre a mi nuevo objeto, o esa era la idea que yo tenía.